# Change page number color in fncychap

Tags: fncychap

I'm using fncychap Glenn option.
My problem is that in the other pages when there is a header and footer i can change the color of the page number by using this code:

```
\usepackage[Glenn]{fncychap}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[LE,RO]{\color{myblue}Header}
\fancyhead[RE,LO]{}
\fancyfoot[CE,CO]{\color{myblue} \leftmark}
\fancyfoot[LE,RO]{\color{myblue} \thepage}
```

but in the pages where there is the chap title the page number is in the default style.
So how can i change the color of page number if there is no header and footer in the page.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Please help us help you by adding a full MWE, see https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx.

Comment: Welcome, this is about header-footers, and has nothing to do with `fncychap`. Please correct the tags when you add an MWE to help us see how the headers and footers are produced in your document.

Comment: Hello johannes, thank you for your reply i edit my post can you see it again please to know what i mean

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The chapter pages are using a different page style called `plain`, which can be adjusted separately to include color:

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[Glenn]{fncychap}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[LE,RO]{\color{blue}Header}
\fancyhead[RE,LO]{}
\fancyfoot[CE,CO]{\color{blue} \leftmark}
\fancyfoot[LE,RO]{\color{blue} \thepage}

\fancypagestyle{plain}{%
  \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}%
  \fancyhf{}%
  \fancyfoot[C]{\color{blue} \thepage}%
}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\chapter{title}

\lipsum
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you  it's working!!!